# mod_lua is missing in 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, apache2, lua

Apache is 2.4.7 in the new 14.04 release.

Various website and release notes mention that lua via mod_lua became available.

There is a lua.load file in /etc/apache2/mods-available, but the corresponding module, mod_lua.so is not present in /usr/lib/apache2/modules.

There is not libapache2-mod-lua to be found in apt.

My question is: how is mod_lua installed?

Thanks!

Comment: Package names: `lua5.1` and `liblua5.1.0-dev` (numbers may vary ;) )

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer: You can't!
The Ubuntu package maintainer did not bother installing the requirements for building this module, and thus it is not included, even though it's a core module. You may file a bug with Ubuntu, or you can check out the Apache Helpdesk PPA at https://launchpad.net/~apache-helpdesk and fetch a version of httpd with mod_lua included.

Comment: apparently this bug was fixed in apache 2.4.9 : https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apache2/+bug/1323930