# Problem with apache

Tags: apache2, lamp, lua

I have problem with apache, when I get configure a LAMP then I write:

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

And everything been fun, but next I wrote

```
cd /etc/apache2/mods-available
sudo cp * /etc/apache2/mods-enabled
```

And when I start a apache I get error log

```
"* Starting web server apache2                                                                    * 
 * The apache2 configtest failed.
Output of config test was:
apache2: Syntax error on line 140 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax error on line 1 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/lua.load: Cannot load /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_lua.so into server: /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_lua.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Action 'configtest' failed."
```

How I can repair this? Please give a simple council because this is my first time on ubuntu. (I have ubuntu 14.04 LTS)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Files in `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled` are supposed to be links to files in `mods-available`, so delete those files which are not links:

```
sudo find /etc/apache2/mods-enabled -type f -exec rm {} +
```

And in the future, use `a2enmod` and `a2dismod`.

Answer (score 1):

Lua support in Apache in 14.04LTS is broken, see also: [mod_lua is missing in 14.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/472868/mod-lua-is-missing-in-14-04)

Apparently, a patch has been around for a while now, but no one has bothered shipping the fix yet. See also: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apache2/+bug/1323930, specifically - have a look at [the suggested work-around](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apache2/+bug/1323930/comments/6).